# CSS transition: fade background color, resetting after

Tags: html, css

I have a list of divs and allow my user to add a new one dynamically by posting new content. If the user posts new content, I'd like to highlight it on the screen by fading the background color of the new div to another color, and fading it back. I'm pretty close:

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1953/

I'm using this CSS to trigger the transition:

```
.backgroundAnimated{
    background-color: #AD310B !important;
    background-image:none !important;
   -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
   -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
   -o-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
   -ms-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-direction: alternate;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
 }
```

I can fade to the other color, but it does not fade back. I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion to accomplish this? I realize there's lots of ways to do this, but I was hoping to contain this entirely in the CSS (except for adding the CSS class dynamically, via jQuery.

Thanks for any suggestions...

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could make use of animation keyframes. No additional javascript needed.

```js
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 $('#newContent').addClass('backgroundAnimated');
});
```

```css
@-o-keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
  100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}
@keyframes fadeIt {
  0%   { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
  50%  { background-color: #AD301B; }
  100% { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
}

.backgroundAnimated{    
    background-image:none !important; 
         -o-animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
            animation: fadeIt 5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Old stuff</div>
<div>Old stuff</div>
<div>Old stuff</div>
<div id="newContent">New stuff, just added</div>

<input type="button" value="test" />
```

Comment: ah - this is pretty ingenious. I like your answer more than mine ;)

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!

Comment: Is there an easy way to run the animation again?

Comment: @althaus Yes, just set the animation-iteration-count property to the number of times you want it to run, or infinite (if you want it to continue). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count

Comment: @Larz but that solution is not resetting the animation after, as the question states. If you click the button a second time it doesn't do it again, at least not in the code snippet run above and using Chrome.

Comment: This is just a demo of the CSS transition itself -- because this is what the original question (at the top of the page) asks for. If you're referring to @ althaus question -- i answered it as I understood it. If you're asking why clicking the "test" button doesn't re-run the animation, this is because additional javascript would be needed to remove the "backgroundAnimated" class from the element, and then add it back. But that's out of scope from the original question, and it has to do with jquery -- not CSS @raspacorp

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm.. If you wanted to keep it in css you could add a setTimeout inside your click event and then add another class.

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 $('#newContent').addClass('backgroundAnimated');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#newContent').addClass('nextBackgroundAnimated');
    }, 5000);
});
```

CSS::

```
.backgroundAnimated{
        background-color: #AD310B !important;
        background-image:none !important;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 5000ms linear;
        -webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-direction: alternate;

        -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-iteration-count: 2;
}
.nextBackgroundAnimated{
        background-color: white !important;
        background-image:none !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1954/

Answer (score 4):

If you can use jquery-ui this might help:

```js
$('input[type=button]').click( function() { 
  var animTime = 1000;
 $('#newContent').addClass('pulse', animTime).removeClass('pulse', animTime);
});
```

```css
.pulse{
        background-color: #AD310B;     
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
     type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  
<div>Old stuff</div>
<div>Old stuff</div>
<div>Old stuff</div>
<div id="newContent">New stuff, just added</div>

<input type="button" value="test" />
```