# Javascript background color transition and reset on HTTP response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a POST request to a server using ajax from Firefox. The input is just some text entry in a box contained within a `div`:

```
<div id="mydiv">
    ...stuff...
</div>
```

If the request is successful, I call a handler to reflect that status. If the request is in error, I call a different handler.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: my_json,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/my/url",
    success: function(result, status, xhr) {
        success_callback();
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        error_callback();
    }

});
```

The success callback doesn't do much. In the error callback, I want to change the background color attribute to red to give a visual indication of the error, and then fade back to the original background color (say, white).

Doing an instantaneous color change is easy:

```
function success_callback() {

    var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    element.style.backgroundColor = "white";

}

function error_callback() {

    var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";

}
```

I've tried doing the fade using a css animation such as

**CSS**

```
.div.error {
     -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
     -webkit-animation-name: error;
     animation-duration: 3s;
     animation-name: error;
} 
@-webkit-keyframes error {
    from {
        background-color: red;
    }
    to {
        background-color: white;
    }
}
```

and then adding the error class in the JavaScript:

**JS**

```
function error_callback() {

    if ($('.div').hasClass('error')) {
        $('.div').removeClass('error');
    else {
        $('.div').addClass('error');
    }
}
```

This works the first time I send a bad POST request, but doesn't on subsequent bad POSTs because I don't think `removeClass` is working correctly (or rather I'm not using it correctly).

I've also tried using jquery-ui following this post [CSS transition: fade background color, resetting after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936811/css-transition-fade-background-color-resetting-after) but that doesn't seem to work for me. Perhaps it something to do with executing an animation in the context of a button click rather than an HTTP response?

Am I heading in the right direction for using this? I'd like to keep within the boundaries of standard jQuery if possible (i.e. stay away from jQuery UI).

Comment: So you are adding the error class in the error callback.  Where are you removing it?

Comment: in your `error_callback` you're essentially toggling the class. What you want to do instead is add it and set a timeout to remove it again. (and btw, you can easily remove 50% of the question text without losing relevant info)

Comment: @Taplar: I tried removing it immediately after the addClass call, i.e. ```$('.div').addClass('error').removeClass('error');``` but this seemed to stop anything happening at all. I also tried detecting the presence of the error class and removing it before adding it again, and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: A quick add and remove like that is most likely not going to give the browser enough time to complete the animation.  And in fact, if both operations happen before the browser gets a chance to try to redraw, an animation may not be started at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because on each successive request you toggle the background colour instead of setting it to a state which reflects the status of the last request.

To fix this you could instead set the `error` class on the element, then use a timeout to remove that class after an arbitrary time, 10 seconds for example:

```
function error_callback() {
  var $div = $('.div').addClass('error');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $div.removeClass('error');
  }, 10000);
}
```

Note that, as @Taplar mentioned in the comment below, you would also need to remember to remove the `error` class when a second successful request is made shortly after an initial failure.

Comment: With the added note that if a request can happen again before the timeout time, the logic may also want to try to remove the class before the next request.